# How Dynamically add a new Input field when clicking a button in blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, matblazor

How add Input field type = text,select,date while click the button in blazor, if its possible in matblazor 
Two button present normally while click
 button 1 create Drop down and text field 
 button 1 create  text field only

```
                        (+) button 1 (+) button 2  

 Step 1:   <Drop-down>    Text field(while click button 1)
 Step 2 Text field(while click button 2)
  Step 3:   <Drop-down>    Text field(while click button 1)
  Step 4:   Text field(while click button 2)
```

Comment: Your question needs more details, also show what you have tried so far

Comment: Create your input elements in a loop and make sure that the loop iterates one more time when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Vencovsky details added

Comment: It's still not very clear. Are they all controls in the same EditForm?  Separate EditForms?  No EditForm?  What do you bind to, and how?

Comment: No Edit form , i send a model class to  drop down, bind string value in text field

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want... I have no idea